# Trouble translating a MongoDB update query into spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

In my mongo database, I have the following document:

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5d1a08d2329a3c1374f176df"),
"associateID" : "1234567",
"associatePreferences" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "NOTIFICATION",
        "serviceCode" : "service-code",
        "eventCode" : "test-template",
        "preferences" : [ 
            "TEXT", 
            "EMAIL"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "URGENT_NOTIFICATION",
        "serviceCode" : "service-code",
        "eventCode" : "test-template",
        "preferences" : [ 
            "TEXT"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I am trying to add new elements to the preferences arrays based off of a given type, serviceCode, and eventCode. I was able to write this query in mongo as shown below:

```
db.user_communication_preferences.update(
   {'associateID':'testassociate'}, 
   {$addToSet:{'associatePreferences.$[element].preferences':"UPDATE"}}, 
   {arrayFilters:[
      {'element.serviceCode':'service-code', 
      'element.eventCode':'test-template',
      'element.type':'NOTIFICATION'
      }
   ]}
)
```

I am trying to translate this query into a java spring boot application. I saw some posts on here about doing this, but I didn't see any that incorporated arrayFilters. Can anyone lead me down the right path?

Comment: are you asking how to write this query in java spring?

Comment: @isaac yes! sorry I was not clear in the question